# Unable to access Git repository in Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, egit, git-pull, bitbucket-server

While trying to run a Git pull from Eclipse, it fails saying:

> Unable to access Stash: Not licensed

The user was able to access this two days ago. There has been no changes in the user credentials (also tried by clearing credentials for push and pull repository)

The user has read access on repository as well as branch in Stash.  What can I do to resolve this situation?

Comment: Hi there. Have you verified that your trial license did not expire?

Comment: Trial license for stash or eclipse? Stash is a full version that we have

Comment: Hi Stash of course. If you have license check to see if you are working on production or staging server.